# Combining information from two excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a problem I am a little stuck on. I could probably brute force it through VBA, but was hoping to keep it on the formula side.  I have 2 sheets that have information on them and a third I am trying to combine them.  Sheet1 has names and the order matters. Sheet2 has names in alphabetical order and some columns that are essentially flags. Sheet3 needs to be only the flagged ones in Sheet2 in Sheet1 order.
For example:

```
Sheet1      Sheet2        Sheet3
tim         bob   x       sally
sally       frank         bob
frank       sally x
bob         tim
```

An Array formula + INDEX can easily pull bob and sally from 2, but is there an easy way to keep them in 1 order?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This formula will give you the output:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5)=0)*(LOOKUP(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5)="x"),),0)),"")
```

It needs to be put in the second row of the output column.  The countif() is what moves to the next one.

Another caveat if there are duplicates it will only pick up the first.

[image]

Comment: Why do astronauts seem to float on the space station?

Comment: @findwindow you are supposed answer it not me.

Comment: You're the one that posted answer =P

Comment: @findwindow they are falling, but they are moving forward so fast that they miss the earth.

Comment: That seems to find the first marked one, but either as array formula or normal, it does not go any further.

Comment: @RyanMJ I promise I did not photoshop the results.  Put it in A2 and copy down.  It is a non CSE array formula, so no need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: lol it would take longer for Scott to photoshop than doing it for real ^_^;

Comment: @RyanMJ I assume you are modifying the formula to suit your needs please post what you are currently trying that is not working.  As stated for the data posted the formula should work.

Answer (score 0):

On scheet 3,

```
CELL A1: Do Select
CELL B1:  Candidate
CELL A2: =lookup(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
CELL B2: =Sheet1!A1
```

Then

- Copy row 2 to sufficient rows below it
- Select all this, activate the insert ribbon and make it a table
- Click the down arrow and deselect the blank
- Scroll to get row 1:1 and column A:A out of scope and f
- Freeze panes.

(Not yet tested, because I am on my tablet)